# Visual Studio 2022, SQL Compare issue in Version 17.4.3

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio IDE(Version: 17.4.3), if we open a database project and try to compare any two  .sql file, we ar getting error as follows:
"Error occured during difference operation: Cannot execute the configured tool."

The above error is happening only for .sql Files and all other files are comparing correctly.

If we rollback to Visual Studio IDE(17.3.6), the above issue is not happening.

Note: In Stack over flow one person has given the option as follows:
Tools \ Options \ Source Control \ Visual Studio Team Foundation Server \ Configure User tools
if we add the vsDiffmerge.exe, then the above error was not appearing, but every time we compare, new instance of VS2022 is opening with the compare file.

Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: We are having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I am having the same problem (VS17.4.4) when trying to see the changes (for git) but only for .sql files of type `Build`. The sql files `PostDeploy` and `None` are displayed correctly in the diff tool.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem in VS Enterprise Version 17.4.4.

It's a bug.

A workaround is to navigate to the file in the Solution Explorer and double-click it. After the .sql file has loaded in the text editor, you can use the context-menu in Solution Explorer or text editor to make a Compare..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I could not compare .sql files from the Pending Changes window, receiving the error noted instead. This worked for my situation:

- Double-click the .sql file to open it in an editing window
- Run the compare operation again

Both steps are from within the Pending Changes window, so it's a quick double-click followed by a right-click and choosing compare. Closing that .sql file causes the compare operation to fail again.